# Unclear exception when reloading families in Design Automation for Revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I have a Revit add-in for design automation that gets all loadable families in a Revit model and executes the following steps for each `family`:

1. Open the family document with `Document familyDocument = doc.EditFamily(family);`
2. Check each family to see if a parameter with name `paramName` is in `familyDocument.FamilyManager.Parameters`
3. If parameter is not found, add parameter to family with `familyDocument.FamilyManager.AddParameter(paramName, groupTypeId, specTypeId, isInstance)`
4. Reload family into Revit model with `familyDocument.LoadFamily(doc, new familyLoadOptions());`

I have a local version of this add-in that works just fine, but when I run my DA4R version, the parameter is not added for the majority of families (e.g. 81 of 95). On the DA report I see the following error:

`A managed exception was thrown by Revit or by one of its external applications at Autodesk.Revit.DB.Document.LoadFamily(Document targetDocument, IFamilyLoadOptions familyLoadOptions)`

The code for the failing transaction is as follows:

```
using (Transaction t = new Transaction(familyDocument))
{
    t.Start("Add Parameter to Family");

    FamilyParameter familyParameter = familyDocument.FamilyManager.AddParameter(paramName, GroupTypeId.IdentityData, SpecTypeId.String.Text, false);

    try
    {
        updatedFamily = familyDocument.LoadFamily(doc, new familyLoadOptions());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message} {e.StackTrace}");
    }

    t.SetFailureHandlingOptions(t.GetFailureHandlingOptions().SetFailuresPreprocessor(new familyLoadFailurePreprocessor()));
    t.Commit();
}
```

Note that the exception comes up *before* I go to commit the transaction.

My loadOptions class is here:

```
public class familyLoadOptions : IFamilyLoadOptions
{
    public bool OnFamilyFound(bool familyInUse, out bool overwriteParameterValues)
    {
        overwriteParameterValues = true;
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnSharedFamilyFound(Family sharedFamily, bool familyInUse, out FamilySource source, out bool overwriteParameterValues)
    {
        source = FamilySource.Family;
        overwriteParameterValues = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I have failure processing implemented here (included even though the exception is raised before the transaction is committed)

```
private void OnFailuresProcessing(object sender, FailuresProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    FailuresAccessor failuresAccessor = e.GetFailuresAccessor();
    failuresAccessor.DeleteAllWarnings();
    e.SetProcessingResult(FailureProcessingResult.Continue);
}
```

```
public class familyLoadFailurePreprocessor : IFailuresPreprocessor
{
    public FailureProcessingResult PreprocessFailures(FailuresAccessor a)
    {
        IList<FailureMessageAccessor> failures = a.GetFailureMessages();

        foreach (FailureMessageAccessor f in failures)
        {
            FailureSeverity fseverity = a.GetSeverity();
  
            if (fseverity == FailureSeverity.Warning)
            {
               a.DeleteWarning(f);
            }
        }

    return FailureProcessingResult.Continue;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how the DA4R version of this process is different other than that I had to implement failure/exception handling automatically, but the error I'm getting isn't specific enough for me to know what to try next or what I am doing wrong. Any ideas??

Comment: This exception is thrown typically when one tries to access Revit data from a thread other than main thread. Nothing in the code you shared in the description suggests you are attempting multi threading. But I want to ensure if it is really the case.

Comment: I seem to vaguely remember a weird observation once that in certain releases of Revit, `LoadFamily` had to be called outside of a transaction; in others, inside. What versions of the Revit engine are you using? Are you testing locally on the exact same versions?

Comment: Not multi-threading. Using Revit 2022 both locally and with DA4R. I tried moving my try/catch block outside of the transaction and still get the same exception.

Comment: I have also tried saving the family using `familyDocument.SaveAs(familyPath)` then using the `familyDocument.LoadFamily(familyPath, new familyLoadOptions(), out Family updatedFamily);` overload instead; this version gives no exception but still fails to load the family.

Comment: This is interesting. Could you email `forge[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com` and refer this SO post? This may need a minimal reproducible sample, if you have one.

Comment: When you send through email, please send sample dataset through a cloud link. 
https://aps.autodesk.com/contact-support, you can fill up the form with details, it will reach us.

Comment: Just sent a sample to the forge.help email; this issue was assigned request number 16729. I will post updates here as I receive them.